# How do you add an iframe to a view in sproutcore?

Tags: iframe, sproutcore

I've got some legacy code to work with and I have no experience with Sprout Core. Searching for the answer has proven inconclusive.

Basically, I need to just an add an iframe to an already existing view, and be able to set the src URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can render a fixed iframe very easily using the `render` function, there is also a SproutCore view, `SC.WebView`, that does this for you in the `:desktop` framework. You should use `SC.WebView` if you expect the `src` to change or if you want to resize the iframe to match the size of its contents.

For example,

```
myWebView: SC.WebView.extend({
  layout: { left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10, border: 1 },
  shouldAutoResize: true, // when the iframe loads, resize it to fit the size of its content
  valueBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('MyApp.currentUrl') // bind the 'src' of the iframe
})
```

Comment: (Side note: I assume the shouldAutoResize property will only work on same-origin content. I believe the resizing fails gracefully in the cross-origin case though so at worst you're safe.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

Assuming the view extends from `SC.View`, the easiest is probably to override the [#render](http://docs.sproutcore.com/#doc=SC.View&method=render&src=false) method and add the iframe yourself:

```
MyApp.MyView = SC.View.extend({
  render: function(context) {
    context.push("<iframe src='http://google.com' />");
  }
});
```